# Unable to populate jqPlot Bar Chart

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

Currently I cant seem to be able to generate any data within my bar chart. I'm unsure if the fault is with the JSON string I have created or with the jQuery code.

Edit: (once i changed the array to single values the basic graph generated but still no bars)

JSON String: `[{"Name":"Poll Results","Serie":[[10],[14],[14],[19]]}]`

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Enable JQuery IntelliSense for Visual Studio
///<reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js2 />

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    urlDataJSON = '/Home/BarChartJSON';

    $.getJSON(urlDataJSON, "", function (data) {
        var dataLines = [];
        var dataLabels = "";
        $.each(data, function (entryindex, entry) {
            dataLines.push(entry['Serie']);
            dataLabels = dataLabels + entry['Name'];
        });

        Plot(dataLines, dataLabels);


        function Plot(dataLines, dataLabels) {

            options = {
                legend: { show: true },
                Title: 'Poll Results',                   
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
                    shadowAngle: 135,
                    renderOptions: {
                        barDirection: 'horizontal'
                    }
                },
                axes: {
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var plot = $.jqplot('barChart', [dataLines], options);
    });
});

</script>

    <h2>barChart</h2>

<div id="barChart" style="height:600px;width:600px;"></div>
```

[image: partially generated Chart]
The screenshot shows what's generating so far.

Comment: I've looked at the JSON string and removed extra data from it. Im now able to generate the basic graph but no bars are appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code for example this are not necessary the options should be a var that goes straight into the chart.

`Plot(dataLines, dataLabels);
        function Plot(dataLines, dataLabels) {`

[Check out this sample of code I did for the previous data you had.](http://jsfiddle.net/cVPjF/7/)

It will work with this `JSON` as well it will only produce a single series.

Comment: So the code you gave me works but instead of generating a bar chart im getting a Line Graph on my local host. Any idea what could cause this?
btw thank you for all the help.

Comment: The only that comes to mind is that the `jqplot.barRenderer.js` is not being found. It is in the `plugins` folder that resides inside the `jqPlot` folder you must have downloaded.

Comment: had the wrong file path for the jqplot plugins. Thanks again mate